# How can I delay an event?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, delay

I would like to delay the execution of an instruction without executing any other one meanwhile.
[Here's the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP1rm.png)

```
public async void parcours_anim(Queue<int> f, noeud[] Arb_b, LabelExpression[] Lbls_A)
{
    int val = 0;
    while (f.ToArray().Length != 0)
    {
        val = f.Dequeue();
        index = Recherche_index(val, Lbls_A);
        //Stop here before executing this instruction for like 2seconds
        Arbre[index].Fill = Brushes.Blue;
        // and then continue
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image

Comment: Thread.Sleep(2000)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx) to wait inside `async` methods.

In your case you can add `await Task.Delay(2000)` in order to wait for 2 seconds and continue execution after that.

Answer (score 0):

Like @dotctor wrote you could use `Task.Delay`, but you must change the method signature to `async Task` as opposed to `async void` otherwise the calling method would not wait for this method to complete

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i tried the Task.Delay but the problem is that it's so fast that it keeps executing the loop and then all the labels are colored at the same time .

Comment: Did you change `async void parcours_anim` to `async Task parcours_anim` ?